# How can I allow the user to change value of fractions?

Tags: c++, class, abstract-data-type

I am supposed to write a program that has num and denom as data members of the Fractions class. I'm also supposed to include a constructor function that sets both equal to 1 or allow for user initialization, an overloaded operator function for +, and a member function that can display an object's data values. Also, it's supposed to prohibit 0 for the denominator's value.
How do I allow the user to change the values for the fractions? Also what should I do to prohibit 0 from being used as the denominator? WHen I run my program it just shows the words in the first 4 lines, but doesn't allow for user input.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Fractions
{
private:
    int num;
    int denom;
public:
    Fractions() : num(1), denom(1) {}
    Fractions(int numerator, int denominator) 
        : num(numerator), denom(denominator) {}

    Fractions& operator+=(Fractions f);

    int numerator() const { return num; }
    int denominator() const { return denom; }

};

Fractions& Fractions::operator+=(Fractions f)
{
    if (denom != f.denom)
    {
        int new_base = denom * f.denom;

        num *= new_base / denom;
        denom = new_base;

        f.num *= new_base / f.denom;
        f.denom = new_base;
    }

    num += f.num;
    return *this;
}

// operator+ is commonly implemented in terms of operator+=
Fractions operator+(Fractions a, const Fractions& b)
{
    return a += b;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Fractions& f)
{
    os << f.numerator();

    if (f.denominator() != 1)
        os << '/' << f.denominator();

    return os;
}

int main()
{
    int w, x, y, z;
    Fractions a(w, x);
    Fractions b(y, z);

    std::cout << "Enter the first numerator: " << endl;
    std::cin >> w;
    std::cout << "Enter the first denominator: " << endl;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "Enter the second numerator: " << endl;
    std::cin >> y;
    std::cout << "Enter the second denominator: " << endl;
    std::cin >> z;

    std::cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << a + b << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Initialize the variables first..

Answer (score 0):

You shoule use the variables after user input:

```
int main()
{
    int w, x, y, z;

    std::cout << "Enter the first numerator: " << endl;
    std::cin >> w;
    std::cout << "Enter the first denominator: " << endl;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "Enter the second numerator: " << endl;
    std::cin >> y;
    std::cout << "Enter the second denominator: " << endl;
    std::cin >> z;

    Fractions a(w, x);
    Fractions b(y, z);

    std::cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << a + b << '\n';
```

}

Comment: I did this but it still doesn't allow for input

Comment: @user3427349 What do you mean "not allow for input"? Please explain it with more details. What is the result and what is your expect?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code.

Most importantly, you initialize the fractions *before* you read the user input, while you should initialize them after. Therefore, the `cout` line in your code will only produce garbage.

In order to allow the user to change the values, you could implement functions

`int & numerator() { return num; }`
and

`int & denominator() { return num; }`

and then use

`a.numerator() = 5` for instance.

Also, you may want to change your code so that the `operator+` is not implemented as `operator+=`.

Comment: Returning references to internal data members is bad programming practice since it turns your class from a black-box to a white-box. Rather have setter/getter pairs when dealing with internal data.

Comment: @user3427349, the reference functions goes inside your class definition.

Comment: @RobbieE, for the general case, you are absolutely right. For this specific (small) class, I don't see the need of having a black box.